# How to merge two Request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-post, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel (5.1) project I need to create a Request for validating a form.

But for this request, i would like to merge two different requests :

The first request :

```
class AdvertisementRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize()
    {

        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'ads_type' => 'required|numeric|in:0,1',
            'category' => 'required|numeric|exists:categories,id',
            'title' => 'required|alpha_num|max:45',
            'description' => 'required|alpha_num|max:2000',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }

}
```

The second request :

```
class UserRegisterRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize()
    {

        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'form_type' => 'required|numeric|in:0,1',
            'user_type' => 'required|numeric|in:0,1',
            'phone' => 'required|phone_number',
            'region' => 'required|numeric|exists:regions,id',
            'department' => 'required|numeric|exists:departments,code',
            'postal_code' => 'required|postal_code',
            'city' => 'alpha|max:45',
            'id_city' => 'required|numeric|exists:cities,id',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha_sp|max:45',
            'first_name' => 'required|alpha_sp|max:45',
            'pseudo' => 'required|alpha|max:45|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|alpha_num|min:6|max:45',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

And i would like to create a third request which combining the two other like that :

```
class UserAdvertisementRegisterRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize()
    {

        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'ads_type' => 'required|numeric|in:0,1',
            'category' => 'required|numeric|exists:categories,id',
            'title' => 'required|alpha_num|max:45',
            'description' => 'required|alpha_num|max:2000',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',

            'form_type' => 'required|numeric|in:0,1',
            'user_type' => 'required|numeric|in:0,1',
            'phone' => 'required|phone_number',
            'region' => 'required|numeric|exists:regions,id',
            'department' => 'required|numeric|exists:departments,code',
            'postal_code' => 'required|postal_code',
            'city' => 'alpha|max:45',
            'id_city' => 'required|numeric|exists:cities,id',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha_sp|max:45',
            'first_name' => 'required|alpha_sp|max:45',
            'pseudo' => 'required|alpha|max:45|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|alpha_num|min:6|max:45',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for do that without duplicate my code ?

Sorry for my bad english :/.

Thank you in advance for you reply !

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way would be to generate the merged list of validation rules in your **UserAdvertisementRegisterRequest::rules** method in the following manner:

```
class UserAdvertisementRegisterRequest extends Request { 
  public function rules()
  {
    return array_merge(
      with(new AdvertisementRequest)->rules(), 
      with(new UserRegisterRequest)->rules()
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to be smart about a merge by extending another request and trying to combine the rules with logic between the parent / child requests. I also had different rules / format for GET vs POST, so my parent request class had a function that would hand me the data based on that, which one of my transformers was expecting.

But ultimately it's better to keep things decoupled, and I found that **it is possible to inject multiple request objects into the controller**. Each request will contain the same values, but each will have validated the request according to their own rules. For my transformer, I only pass the version of the request that the transformer is expecting so it can call the extended get function and transform from there.

```
public function store(
    StoreEventRequest          $storeEventRequest, 
    UserListRequest            $userListRequest, 
    UserListRequestTransformer $transformer
) {
    $eventDetails     = $storeEventRequest->all();
    $userListIterator = $transformer->requestToUserList($userListRequest);
    ...
}
```