# Combining Form Requests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two requests that validate forms:

- StoreProductRequest (validates a newly created product)
- StoreProductBuildRequest (validates the components within the product)

In the 'edit' view, this functionality is combined into one form.

What is the best way to run through both form requests when submitting this form? I would rather avoid creating a new request (StoreProductAndBuildRequest?) as this isn't very DRY.

*Related, but I wonder if there's a cleaner / more Laravel way:
[How to merge two Request in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256263/how-to-merge-two-request-in-laravel)*

Comment: Maybe a redirect from StoreProductRequest (once is successfully completed) to StoreProductBuildRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried injecting both form requests?

```
public function update(StoreProductRequest $requestOne, StoreProductBuildRequest $requestTwo)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: No, but the combined form = one $request

Comment: StoreProductRequest $request, StoreProductBuildRequest $request = Error "Redefinition of parameter $request".

Comment: StoreProductRequest $requestOne, StoreProductBuildRequest $requestTwo = Error "Undefined variable: request"

Comment: don't forget to change the references in your code to $requestOne || $requestTwo

Comment: @TomHoad Make sure you use the variables you define inside the method, i.e. $requestOne->input() and $requestTwo->input();

Answer (score 0):

You can define rules in one request file for multiple request like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class AdmissionRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return match(Route::currentRouteName()) {
            'admission.store' => $this->store(),
            'admission.update' => $this->update()
        };
    }

    /**
     * Validate Rules for store Request
     */
    public function store()
    {
        // Your Store Request array
    }

    /**
     * Validate Rules for update Request
     */
    public function update()
    {
        // Your Update Request Rule array
    }
}
```